# GridView is not showing retrieved data from Json

Tags: java, android, gridview

I have a gridview which should show emojies that are retrieved from the server as urls, I was able to retrieve the urls and put it inside an arraylist, however using the gridview adapter, no images show at all, I've tried debugging by handcoding the url outside the for loop and it showed the image, which means that nothing is wrong with my adapter, also when I try to hardcode the url inside the for loop like arraylist.add("the url") no image appears, here's my code, please advise why the images are not showing, appreciate your assistance

BottomSheetDialog_Smiles.java

```
Communicator.getInstance().on("subscribe start", new Emitter.Listener() {

       @Override
       public void call(Object... args) {
           try {
               JSONDictionary response = (JSONDictionary) args[0];
               String str = response.get("emojiPack").toString();
               JSONArray emojies = new JSONArray(str);

               for (int i = 0; i < emojies.length(); i++) {

                   JSONObject response2 = (JSONObject) 
                   emojies.getJSONObject(i);

                   emojiModel = new EmojiModel((String) 
                   response2.get("urlFile"));
                   emojiUrl = emojiModel.getEmojiFile();
                   JSONDictionary t = 
               JSONDictionary.fromString(response2.toString());
                   emojiModel.init(t);
                   emojieModels.add(emojiModel);
               }

               ImageAdapter2 emojiAdapter = new 
               ImageAdapter2(getApplicationContext(), emojieModels);
               gridView2.setAdapter(emojiAdapter);

           } catch (JSONException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

       }
   });
```

ImageAdapter2.java

```
    public class ImageAdapter2 extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> emojieImages = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Constructor
    public ImageAdapter2(Context context, ArrayList<String> 
    emojieImagesList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.emojieImages = emojieImagesList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return emojieImages.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return emojieImages.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    public class Holder {
        ImageView imageView;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup 
    parent) {

        Holder holder = new Holder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
  getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.smiles_items_layout, null);

        holder.imageView = (ImageView) 
        grid.findViewById(R.id.smile_image_view);

        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(emojieImages.get(position))
                .fit()
                .centerInside()
                .into(holder.imageView);

        return grid;
       }
   }
```

EmojiModel.java

```
public class EmojiModel {
    private int id;
    private int price;
    public String urlFile;

public EmojiModel(String urlFile) {
    this.id=id;
    this.price=price;
    this.urlFile=urlFile;
}

public String getEmojiFile() {
    return urlFile;
}

public void init(JSONDictionary data){
    try{
        urlFile = (String) data.get("urlFile");
        id = Integer.parseInt((String) data.get("id"));
        price = Integer.parseInt((String) data.get("price"));

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please add your json response with your question.

Comment: Whenever I run the app on debug mode, it shows that the arraylist size = 2, urlFile = "The  url get displayed"

Comment: what is the response in  urlFile =   OR may be Picasso image is not loading.

Comment: I suspect that Picasso image is not loading, but why would that happen, I guess there is nothing wrong with my code, or maybe I shoud look for another approach, what do you suggest ?

Comment: please try below ans and tell me  Log is success or error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Picasso.with(this)
    .load(imageUrl)
    .fit()
    .centerInside()
    .into(imageViewFromUrl, new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            Log.i(TAG, "succcess");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError() {
            Log.i(TAG, "error");
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: The log is not coming up at all

Comment: please add your json response here.

Comment: emojiModels={ArrayList@6034} size=2
0 ==> id = 5, price = 0, urlFile = "http://The url.png"
1 ==> id = 6, price = 0, urlFile="http://The url.png"

Comment: your image URL is not open.

Comment: I've tried opening it up on my PC and it opened successfully